# opencart get product by model name

Tags: php, opencart

Is there any way to load a product by its model name in opencart,
The site i am working on has many related products with the same sub model number.
see below for example.

product model names:

```
thq-0034,
thq-0034-big,
thq-0034-small,
thq-0034-blue,
thq-0035,
thq-0035-big,
thq-0035-small,
thq-0035-blue,
```

ie. put a link from product thq-0034/5's product page to the thq-0034/5-big or thq-0034/5-blue 
Companion product without making them all related products in the admin menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to run a query on the `product` table

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT product_id FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product` WHERE `model` LIKE 'thq-0034%'");
```

This will return an array of results, with a `product_id` key for each product matching